# How to create MVC application and need good website to learn more about this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Anyone suggest me to good source to learn more about MVC4. I Need to learn this from the scratch.Thanks in Advance !!.

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 2):

Please do have a look here. it starts from scratch (a very basic start) 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: They have good tutorials there.

Comment: Yes!!, They start from very basic- since it was mentioned that he has to start from scratch